# Class found in a Java application but not in JSF?

Tags: java, class, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to use bacnet4j with JSF.

I build an application in .java which turn on/off a lamp, but if I try to call the same method from a JSF page (which communicates with my manage bean) , gives me :

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com/serotonin/bacnet4j/type/Encodable
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/serotonin/bacnet4j/type/Encodable
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.serotonin.bacnet4j.type.Encodable
```

But I'm pretty sure that the class is there, because if not my java application don't work, right ?

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm pretty sure that the class is there"? Are you sure it is in your web app class path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR file containing this class should go in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

A plain Java Application does not use the same classpath as a Java Web Application. For a plain Java Application the classpath is usually specified by `-cp` or `-classpath` argument in `java` command, or if unspecified, by `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable, or if being a JAR, by `Class-Path` entry in JAR's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. For a Java Web Application the classpath covers by default the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and `/WEB-INF/classes` folder and server's `/lib` (and more) folders and any custom folders which you can specify in server-specific configuration, such as `shared.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties` in case of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

[NoClassDefFound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) means that the class was available at compilation but not at runtime.  You need to add the jar-file with the appropriate class to your war (or add it to the application server classpath)